# radiobutton styling without label

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to style with css only, a radiobutton without having a label? Radiobuttons with label does seem to appear ok, but the ones not having a label, do not appear at all. Didn't find any proper solution through the internet for my problem.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJjru/

```
input.form-radio:empty{
  margin-left: -9999px}

input.form-radio:empty ~ .description {
  position: relative;
  float: left
  text-indent: 30px
  margin-top: 0 }


input.form-radio:empty ~ .description:before {
  position: absolute
  display: block
  top: 3px
  bottom: 0
  left: 0
  content: ''
  width: 10px
  height: 10px
  background: #fff
  border-radius: 30px
  border: 2px solid #fdd68d }

input.form-radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ .description.option:before {
  text-indent: .9em
  color: #C2C2C2
  background-color: orange }

input.form-radio:hover:not(:checked) ~ .description {
  color: #888 }

input.form-radio:checked ~ .description:before {
  text-indent: .9em
  background-color: orange }

input.form-radio:checked ~ .description {
  color: #777}
```

Comment: What kind of styling are you trying to apply?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: an example that shows the problem would help a lot

Comment: Maybe some code would help

Comment: I've tried to change the label with the class which the radiobutton is wrapped, the checkboxes appeared, but they are not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes" and "no".

"Yes" you can style radio buttons like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mEGF7/).
But they are boring and ugly.

CSS

```
.radiotest {
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

The answer is "NO" if you want to make them pretty, and is answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325990/styling-radio-button-without-label) in an old discussion.